# "Select a tool" error Saga: Accumulated cost (isotropic)

Tags: qgis, dem, saga

I'm trying to run Saga's accumulated cost operation in QGIS on a DEM and set of raster destination points, but keep receiving an "Error: select a tool" in the log after a failed run. There are no other options to specify in the Saga Accumulated Cost algorithm (at least that are presented in it's processing toolbox dialogue), and am not sure what is producing this error. How do I resolve this?

Alternatively, is there another means of generating an accumulated cost map? Saga's algorithm is proving to be extremely difficult to use.